# Create Parent and Child Records Through Dialogs

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to create a dialog that do the following:

1. The dialog will run when I want to copy an entity (Submission). So, the first step is to copy the parent record (Submission);
2. After that, I want to copy as well the child records (Claims) and associate those children to the copied entity (Submission).

So far I can copy the Submission, but I can't copy the Claims and associate them to the new Submission.

Do you guys know how can I do that? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write code to do this, a custom workflow activity would be probably be a good option.

Comment: And how do I call this activity? Can you give me a basic example?

Comment: @Kiwanax Create it as an On Demand Workflow, and call it how you normally call On Demand Workflows.  Could even create a ribbon button that does it.